# amazon s3 mount with fuse and s3fs

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, s3fs

I have an Nginx Server with php-fpm installed on Centos 6.4

### 1. Current status:

I use the NFS server to hold versions and files, Nginx mounts the NFS and serves files from it.
this scenario is working and handles large volumes of traffic

### 2. Desired scenario

Replace the NFS with S3 and mount it using fuse & s3fs.
In that scenario the server fails when forced to handle high traffic.

Is fuse & s3fs much slower or am i missing something?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in thinking that S3 behaves like an NFS mount. It does not. NFS and other disk volumes work on blocks, s3 works on entire objects. Generally when accessing files from s3fs, the entire file is copied to tmp and it has much higher latency than disk access.

A couple of solutions:

If you prefer NFS, you can set up an NFS share from a separate instance and mount it on the instances that need it.

Otherwise, you can deploy your code directly to the instance itself, (which is something you can automate) and run your code from there. Static assets could be served directly from s3 via cloudfront and/or with cloudfront using a custom origin.

Comment: understood...actually i currently use the first solution you described.
my question is is it ok to automate the copy of the S3 to the local server and will it be (performance wise) ok?

Comment: can you please explain about the custom origin? i work with cloudflare as CDN but though about moving to cloudfront (i'm just not sure about the costs...do i pay for both s3 data and cloudfront data?)

Comment: On your first question, yes it will be ok. On your second question, you can use cloudfront with either a custom domain or an s3 bucket as an origin. If you use s3, you will pay for s3 storage and a little bit of bandwidth as files are transferred to the cloudfront endpoints (Can be reduced with long expiration).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) project, it allows you to mount S3 bucket as local directory (we are using fuse). 
As `datasage` mentioned earlier: you can't really compare NFS with S3, as these two are completely different filesystems used in different scenarios. [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) let you upload / download files and list directory content. Anything extra (like appending data to a file) is not supported.